# Python 3.5 'list' object has no attribute 'min' and unorderable types: str() < int() and

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_min.htm) using python 3.5, however I'm getting errors instead of the expected results. Also, I would appreciate if you explain what the indicated line below does.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]

list1, list2 = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc'], [456, 700, 200]
print ("min value element : ", min(list1))
print ("min value element : ", min(list2))

plt.scatter(x, y,  color='red') 
#please explain this line:
plt.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], color='blue', linewidth=3) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

In python 3, comparison operations are stricter for the built in data types.

```
>>> min([123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc'])
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

`min()` tries to compare `'xyz' < 123` which was possible in python 2, but not in python 3.

If you want to get the smallest member of a list, use `min(list)`, not `list.min()`.

This should work, for instance:

```
plt.plot([min(y), max(y)], [min(x), max(x)], color='blue', linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you need to pass the lists into min and max like this:

```
plt.plot([min(y), max(y)], [min(y), max(y)], color='blue', linewidth=3)
```

Right now this will just plot a line between [1,1] and [5,5].

If you want to plot x and y against each other you could do this:

```
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue', linewidth=3)
```

In the case of list1 you have a list with ints and strings so the strings will just be ignored by min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays have min and max methods, Python lists don't. Python does have [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function), which are slower on numpy arrays in particular since they would iterate over all entries as Python objects. That tutorial erroneously refers to the functions as [methods](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method), and they operate on iterables, not necessarily lists.